# CSS properties that hold multiple values in Backbone Model

Tags: jquery, css, backbone.js

So, I have a model in backbone representing a Button, and I have some defaults on my model, regarding it's style (background color, border-radius etc). Is there a way to access certain css properties that hold multiple values, all at once? (eg. border: 1px solid black) 
Or I will have to do something like this:

```
setCssStyle: function () {
    this.$el.css({
        'border-width': myButton.get('borderwidth') + 'px',
        'border-style': myButton.get('borderstyle'),
        'border-color': myButton.get('bordercolor')
    });
}
```

How would my model defaults change If I could set multiple css values at once? If I am correct, the multiple values would be held in an array like in the following example

```
var Button = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults {
        border: {width:1, style:'solid', color:'#00000'}
    }
});
```

Instead of:

```
var Button = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        borderwidth: 1,
        borderstyle: 'solid',
        bordercolor: '#000000'
    }
})
```

what happens to other css properties that don't have this 'workaround' such as box-shadow for example?
is there a more convenient way to set the following css properties in my setCssStyles method?

```
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
```

Comment: A button is not data and should not be represented by a model.

Comment: well it is data, if you consider a mock-up application where you can drag and drop buttons, and various other elements in a div.
The model holds css data, which the user can manipulate to alter the appeareance of the button.

Comment: It depends (as usual) on the details. I think you'd end up representing things in the intersection of what your application needed and what jQuery would accept. In some cases that would be things like `'box-shadow': 'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff'` and string parsing, sometimes broken down properties in an object (`border: { width: 1, ... }`). Careful with objects and arrays in [`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) though, you might want to use a `defaults` function to avoid accidental reference sharing.